# Nodejs: avoid duplicate data on declare mongoose document

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

This my code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export type data = {
  name: string
  active: boolean
}

export interface document extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string,
  active: boolean
}

export interface model extends mongoose.Model<document> {
  build(attrs: document): document
}
```

I use `data` for reference to output result and use **`document`** for mongoose model.

But **`document`** and **`data`** are same!

How can I use data for document to avoid this section?

```
{
  name: string
  active: boolean
}
```

I tried this ways but does not work for me:

```
export interface document extends mongoose.Document = data

export interface document extends mongoose.Document {
  data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with Omit:

```
interface document extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string,
  active: boolean
}

export type data = Omit<document, keyof mongoose.Document>
```